# How to change background colour in an SVG image?

Tags: css, svg, background-color

This is an example SVG image, to which I need to change background colour, from the current white to transparent (or black).
So far I could only change the foreground colour.

```html
<svg xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" viewBox="5 5 90 90" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" id="svg14" sodipodi:docname="icon_link.svg" inkscape:version="0.92.1 r15371">
      <metadata
         id="metadata20">
        <rdf:RDF>
          <cc:Work
             rdf:about="">
            <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
            <dc:type
               rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
          </cc:Work>
        </rdf:RDF>
      </metadata>
      <defs
         id="defs18" />
      <sodipodi:namedview
         pagecolor="#ffffff"
         bordercolor="#666666"
         borderopacity="1"
         objecttolerance="10"
         gridtolerance="10"
         guidetolerance="10"
         inkscape:pageopacity="0"
         inkscape:pageshadow="2"
         inkscape:window-width="787"
         inkscape:window-height="620"
         id="namedview16"
         showgrid="false"
         inkscape:zoom="1.888"
         inkscape:cx="50"
         inkscape:cy="62.5"
         inkscape:window-x="262"
         inkscape:window-y="18"
         inkscape:window-maximized="0"
         inkscape:current-layer="svg14" />
      <title
         id="title2">1</title>
      <desc
         id="desc4">Created with Sketch.</desc>
      <g
         stroke="none"
         stroke-width="1"
         fill="none"
         fill-rule="evenodd"
         sketch:type="MSPage"
         id="g8"
         style="fill:#ff0000">
        <path
           d="M72.6749171,46.3009857 L27.3261728,46.3009857 L27.3261728,53.9297668 L72.6749171,53.9297668 L72.6749171,46.3009857 Z M84.6466542,29 L63.3361992,29 C57.6266014,29 52.9828534,33.6448379 52.9828534,39.3533458 L52.9828534,41.9416822 L60.6116345,41.9416822 L60.6116345,39.3533458 C60.6116345,37.8504759 61.8333293,36.6287811 63.3361992,36.6287811 L84.6466542,36.6287811 C86.1495241,36.6287811 87.3712189,37.8504759 87.3712189,39.3533458 L87.3712189,60.8774067 C87.3712189,62.3802766 86.1495241,63.6019714 84.6466542,63.6019714 L63.3361992,63.6019714 C61.8333293,63.6019714 60.6116345,62.3802766 60.6116345,60.8774067 L60.6116345,58.2890703 L52.9828534,58.2890703 L52.9828534,60.8774067 C52.9828534,66.5859146 57.6266014,71.2307525 63.3361992,71.2307525 L84.6466542,71.2307525 C90.3551621,71.2307525 95,66.5859146 95,60.8774067 L95,39.3533458 C95,33.6448379 90.3551621,29 84.6466542,29 L84.6466542,29 Z M39.3894553,58.2890703 L47.0182364,58.2890703 L47.0182364,60.8774067 C47.0182364,66.5859146 42.3733986,71.2307525 36.6648907,71.2307525 L15.3533458,71.2307525 C9.64483786,71.2307525 5,66.5859146 5,60.8774067 L5,39.3533458 C5,33.6448379 9.64483786,29 15.3533458,29 L36.6648907,29 C42.3733986,29 47.0182364,33.6448379 47.0182364,39.3533458 L47.0182364,41.9416822 L39.3894553,41.9416822 L39.3894553,39.3533458 C39.3894553,37.8504759 38.1677605,36.6287811 36.6648907,36.6287811 L15.3533458,36.6287811 C13.8504759,36.6287811 12.6287811,37.8504759 12.6287811,39.3533458 L12.6287811,60.8774067 C12.6287811,62.3802766 13.8504759,63.6019714 15.3533458,63.6019714 L36.6648907,63.6019714 C38.1677605,63.6019714 39.3894553,62.3802766 39.3894553,60.8774067 L39.3894553,58.2890703 Z"
        fill="none"
           sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"
           id="path6"
           style="fill:#ffff00"
     />
      </g>
    </svg>
```

tried to modify `pagecolor` without success.

How can I do it, possibly without using CSS?

Comment: Your SVG has no background color set, so it should be transparent already.  There should be nothing you need to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inkscape tends to generate grossly bloated files. Here's a cleaned-up version for you:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 90 90">
  <defs>
    <mask id="chain">
      <rect x="4" y="28" width="34" height="34" fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="7" rx="7" />
      <rect x="52" y="28" width="34" height="34" fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="7" rx="7" />
      <rect x="21" y="39" width="48" height="12" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  
  <!-- Uncomment this for manual background -->
  <!--rect fill="#000" width="90" height="90" /-->
  
  <rect fill="#ff0" width="90" height="90" mask="url(#chain)" />
</svg>
```

You'll notice that not only is this significantly smaller than your file, it's also easier to see what's going on: I'm using two rounded-corner squares, and a rectangle for the link, using a mask to clip out the shape. Then, flood-fill with your colour using the shape as a mask to get the result.

This has no background colour defined. If used as an image file, it will by transparent to reveal any background behind it. Or you can uncomment the indicated line to enforce a background on the icon.

Comment: How can I change the background color using CSS? I tried the .fill{color:#f00} but it's change the only text color.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

add `style="background-color: #000;"` inline to `<svg>`

Check demo [here](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/xdeRMy)

Comment: Yes, it works. Is it possible to set it to transparent?

Comment: @Pietro yes you can set the property to transparent `style="background-color: transparent;"`.You can verfiy this by editing the example in codepen by giving the `body` different color (`body {
  background-color: red;
}`)